# Select has to be double click on chrome when sticky

Tags: css, google-chrome, sticky

Using **Chrome** and **native sticky**, I have a problem with a select where I have to click two times before being able to select an option when :

- the select is in a sticky container
- the sticky container is being sticky (scroll down has been performed)

**How can I reduce the dropdown selection to 1 clic without prior focus on Google Chrome?**

Here is a fiddle to illustrate the bug:
https://jsfiddle.net/ckkpwyf6/

HTML:

```
<html><head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <style type="text/css">
    body{
  font-family: Arial;
  }

form{
  float: right;
  display: block;
  position: -webkit-sticky;position: sticky;
  top: 10px;
  width: 30%;
  }

div{
  display: block;
  width: 70%;
  }

p{margin:10px 0;}
  </style>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<main>
   <form action="#" method="GET">
    <input placeholder="Lorem ipsum" value="Lorem ipsum" type="text">
    <select name="number">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2" selected="selected">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
   </form>
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus iaculis tortor elit, ut porttitor lectus ultrices vel. Donec eget hendrerit lorem. Proin nulla dolor, consequat tempus efficitur sit amet, aliquet in massa. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc pretium nunc et eros iaculis dapibus. Aliquam quis orci molestie tortor eleifend mattis nec sed est. Curabitur dignissim tincidunt augue, quis consequat elit rhoncus quis.</p>

<p>Nunc placerat a lacus in tristique. Nam eleifend porta mi, id rhoncus massa accumsan quis. Integer velit nisl, consequat id volutpat ac, scelerisque eget nibh. Pellentesque eget efficitur felis. Morbi ac tincidunt lacus, nec tempus velit. Mauris porta leo id magna ultricies consequat. In vestibulum lacus vel egestas sagittis. Vivamus rutrum porta libero, non dignissim augue viverra id. Phasellus faucibus felis eu orci aliquet, eu malesuada mi venenatis.</p>

<p>Nam et purus lacinia, euismod felis sit amet, rhoncus odio. Ut blandit ullamcorper quam, non eleifend tellus venenatis vitae. Etiam lacinia eros non aliquet varius. Donec sit amet pulvinar ante. Vestibulum justo dolor, lobortis vitae sem in, vehicula varius felis. Nullam efficitur dignissim augue sit amet sodales. Morbi vel ornare est. Integer sodales in arcu sed pellentesque. Cras quis placerat metus. Vestibulum vulputate rutrum ornare.</p>

<p>Morbi pulvinar consectetur quam, ac semper risus malesuada vel. Aliquam a finibus massa. Nunc interdum mauris velit, non pulvinar velit vehicula sit amet. Ut dictum nec sapien a vestibulum. Cras maximus metus sagittis dui eleifend, ac rhoncus elit dapibus. Nam ut risus vitae nisl egestas mattis et eu elit. Donec in dolor urna. Sed eu lobortis nisi, a vehicula ipsum. Quisque fermentum ac felis ac vehicula. Fusce eget accumsan risus, a fringilla odio. Suspendisse quis tristique felis. Duis consectetur ex sed tincidunt vestibulum. Vivamus vel varius ex.</p>

<p>Vivamus faucibus venenatis maximus. In vitae sapien eu orci rhoncus maximus at vel est. Cras scelerisque dui egestas, molestie justo sit amet, efficitur justo. Integer egestas est fermentum sem rutrum elementum. Pellentesque sagittis a mi a feugiat. Phasellus sed suscipit eros. Vestibulum sed turpis bibendum, porta purus fringilla, rutrum sem. Ut nibh sem, facilisis vel porttitor sed, efficitur ut mauris. In eget pretium eros. Aenean nec orci a massa congue consectetur quis non ligula. Nam vestibulum, tellus ut faucibus pretium, purus libero rhoncus nisl, vel facilisis arcu leo aliquet risus.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus iaculis tortor elit, ut porttitor lectus ultrices vel. Donec eget hendrerit lorem. Proin nulla dolor, consequat tempus efficitur sit amet, aliquet in massa. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc pretium nunc et eros iaculis dapibus. Aliquam quis orci molestie tortor eleifend mattis nec sed est. Curabitur dignissim tincidunt augue, quis consequat elit rhoncus quis.</p>

<p>Nunc placerat a lacus in tristique. Nam eleifend porta mi, id rhoncus massa accumsan quis. Integer velit nisl, consequat id volutpat ac, scelerisque eget nibh. Pellentesque eget efficitur felis. Morbi ac tincidunt lacus, nec tempus velit. Mauris porta leo id magna ultricies consequat. In vestibulum lacus vel egestas sagittis. Vivamus rutrum porta libero, non dignissim augue viverra id. Phasellus faucibus felis eu orci aliquet, eu malesuada mi venenatis.</p>

<p>Nam et purus lacinia, euismod felis sit amet, rhoncus odio. Ut blandit ullamcorper quam, non eleifend tellus venenatis vitae. Etiam lacinia eros non aliquet varius. Donec sit amet pulvinar ante. Vestibulum justo dolor, lobortis vitae sem in, vehicula varius felis. Nullam efficitur dignissim augue sit amet sodales. Morbi vel ornare est. Integer sodales in arcu sed pellentesque. Cras quis placerat metus. Vestibulum vulputate rutrum ornare.</p>

<p>Morbi pulvinar consectetur quam, ac semper risus malesuada vel. Aliquam a finibus massa. Nunc interdum mauris velit, non pulvinar velit vehicula sit amet. Ut dictum nec sapien a vestibulum. Cras maximus metus sagittis dui eleifend, ac rhoncus elit dapibus. Nam ut risus vitae nisl egestas mattis et eu elit. Donec in dolor urna. Sed eu lobortis nisi, a vehicula ipsum. Quisque fermentum ac felis ac vehicula. Fusce eget accumsan risus, a fringilla odio. Suspendisse quis tristique felis. Duis consectetur ex sed tincidunt vestibulum. Vivamus vel varius ex.</p>

<p>Vivamus faucibus venenatis maximus. In vitae sapien eu orci rhoncus maximus at vel est. Cras scelerisque dui egestas, molestie justo sit amet, efficitur justo. Integer egestas est fermentum sem rutrum elementum. Pellentesque sagittis a mi a feugiat. Phasellus sed suscipit eros. Vestibulum sed turpis bibendum, porta purus fringilla, rutrum sem. Ut nibh sem, facilisis vel porttitor sed, efficitur ut mauris. In eget pretium eros. Aenean nec orci a massa congue consectetur quis non ligula. Nam vestibulum, tellus ut faucibus pretium, purus libero rhoncus nisl, vel facilisis arcu leo aliquet risus.</p>
  </div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No one seems to want to tackle this question since it has more to do with the chrome quirks mode than with the code. What you're doing in this example is 100% achievable using `position: fixed;` since it becomes "sticky" from the beginning

Comment: of course the fiddle here is really just to point out the bug, the page where I have this issue is much more complex and the position fixed is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

You can bypass the bug by adding an attribute "**onmouseover**" to the  element `onmouseover="this.focus()"`

https://jsfiddle.net/su9ygvd5/